# Rails 3/ActiveRecord: How to switch/change table name during request dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to change the table name of the ActiveRecord model class during request dynamically.

---

For example, there are many tables having similar structure(columns):

```
mydb:
  sample_data_12222
  sample_data_12223
  sample_data_12224
  sample_data_12225
  ...
```

So, what I want to do is...

_1. Defining the base model class like:

```
class SampleData < ActiveRecord::Base
```

_2. Changing the target table during request like:

```
def action_method
  SampleData.set_table_name "sample_data_#{params[:id]}"
  @rows = SampleData.all
```

---

It seems that above code is right if it's run on non-threaded environment (like on Passenger/mod_rails).
But it's **not thread-safe**, so it may not work on threaded-environment (like on JRuby-Rack).

Also I tried creating the delived class like this:

```
def action_method
  @model_class = Class.new(SampleData)
  @model_class.set_table_name "sample_data_#{params[:id]}"
  @rows = @model_class.all
```

But it cause memory leaks, though the delived model class is not used any more after request was completed.  :(

---

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I was looking for something similar (but a little more simple). Hopefully my answer will (still) help you@

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for marking your answer accepted. ;) I reached somthing similar to your answer.

Comment: In case someone needs to play with something similar in the future, see this Q&A:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537951/changing-table-name-at-query-run-time-in-a-rails-application/52539763#52539763

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use class variables:

```
class SampleData < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    @@model_class = {}

    # Create derived class for id
    @@model_class[id] = Class.new(SampleData)
    @@model_class[id].set_table_name "sample_data_#{id}"
    # Repeat for other IDs
  end
end
```

Now you can use the derived classes over and over, without causing memory leaks.

Depending on your actual situation (eg you do not know the IDs on beforehand), you could check whether the id is already present in the Hash dynamically and add it if not.

Comment: How would you use your origional class as well as the @@model_class[id] class?

Comment: @veger this is cool solution but doesnt work for associations.

user = SampleData.model_class[44].find(2) /* queries table - sample_data_44 */
user.addresses /* queries table - addresses, not addresses_44 */

Comment: Should I make a loop if I want 10 tables? `# Repeat for other IDs`

Comment: Sure why not, unless you need to do some specific things making the loop impractical. Note that asking non-related-to-the-OP questions should be done in a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), especially since this one is very old!