# Dynamicaly creating a model with a real DB as attribute of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table named "tables" and inside there is a column named table_name. And, on my DB inside other schema I have this table. Like:

```
db: tables
id  table_name  other_attributes
 1  minerals    ...
 2  animals     ...

db: minerals
id  name  type
 1  rock  nil
 2  sand  nil
```

The tables doesn't have the same structure. I would like to call my model like:

```
> tab = Table.find(1)
> tab.elements.all
=> [ {id: 1, name: 'rock', type: nil}, {id: 2, name: 'sand', type: nil} ]
```

And use any kind of active record tasks inside this .elements...
I didn't find any way and the closest article that I found was this: [Rails 3/ActiveRecord: How to switch/change table name during request dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347570/rails-3-activerecord-how-to-switch-change-table-name-during-request-dynamically)

Comment: Just my 2 cents, if you can't figure out how to do this the "railsy" way. You could always `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")` to just create the tables with manual SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time after this question I think (just think because I dont know if it is really right) here is the answer:

```
class TableMaster < ActiverRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :db
  after_find do
    me = self
    me.db = Class.new ( ActiveRecord::Base ) do
        self.table_name = "schema." + me.tablename
    end
    true
  end
end
```

Just put it inside the model and there will be a full functional Active Record model inside another.
I'm really happy that I got this answer but am still in doubt if it's really right. Please send me some sugestions of it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best approach in your case it to perform a direct update to the database. If you don't like to write SQL directly, you can rely on some high-level libraries such as [Sequel](http://rubygems.org/gems/sequel) that in this case are a little bit less coupled to the conventions imposed by ActiveRecord.

Comment: I have no problems writing SQL directly, but as Andrew Wei said, I would like to do it "railsy" way! :) I will study this Sequel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSql you might be interested in hstore - http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore. Using hstore (it stores json) would simplify very much your db and application :)